# Swift3 How to implement bottom sheet in iOS like in android

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

In my application i have to display bottom sheet same as in android, My requirement is as follows, In Screen1 if we swipe then it should changes like scree2 , and the same scenario required on button click (Blue background color button), Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use UISwipeGesture recognizer and use the same function as target for both the SwipeGesture as well as the button Action.

Comment: You could embed your original view in a UIScrollView and make it "taller". The user could then scroll up and down as he wishes.

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan  The background image is available in one view controller and the scrollable content is available in another view controller , If i use swipe gesture then how can i show that only the text content is moving? Help me

Comment: @BogdanFarca In android they did it by using botttom sheet . If i use scroll view then how can i manage on button click and swipe.

Comment: Well I had done a similar thing some time back. Here is what I did. Loaded the data into a webView made the background clear and scroll the view normally and reload the webview on swipe and button click.

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan Can i have the sample code or reference link

Comment: I would mail it to you in some time.

Comment: I would use PanGesture, a little bit more customizable, and I would create a xib view exactly like this with bottom half (table view) in seperate view inside xib and I would add height constraint and it would be zero at the beginning. I would then change button constraint constant on gesture and i would animate it with basic animation and use layoutIfNeeded to animate constraint change, because that layouts your subviews.

Comment: @MaheshNarla: when you click the button you make the scroll view scroll to the bottom. But you don't have to use the button at all, just put a small down arrow at the bottom to hint the user they could swipe up for more.

Comment: You can use UITableView, Initially hide cell then unhide when user swipe tableview.

Comment: @BogdanFarca As per the client requirement  It should work on both up swipe and button click (Blue background color button)

Comment: @MaheshNarla: So you're covered by using the UIScrollview. The button could scroll the view to the bottom.

Comment: @ZaidPathan If i hide cell then user doesn't experience the swiping

Comment: @MaheshNarla How many possible entries are there in bottom?
If more than 10, then go with dynamic table view else go with other solutions like scrollview/stackview etc.

Comment: @BogdanFarca I haven't used scrollview in this i have taken two screen A and B . . I'm trying to present screen B on  Screen A, But i'm not able to implement the swiping as in android, Actually while we swiping the bottom sheet user should experience that the content is moving up.

Comment: @MaheshNarla : Hmm, the scroll view is extremely simple to implement but if you want 2 views, then use a gesture recognizer to trigger a segue from **view 1** to **view 2** and use a custom transition between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIAlertController` with .ActionSheet for the preferredStyle or create custom `UIView` with needed logic.